# Python, Selenium trying to target image by class xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click the first image that appears on a page through python/selenium.

The html code is:

```
<div class="flex-none ph1 mt2 w-sixth-ns w-third">
    <a class="aspect-ratio--1x1 relative db bg-near-black hover-bg-dark-primary bg-animate outline-0 no-underline overflow-hidden br1" href="https://users/792647/pictures/88860858" title="Random name cannot use this to link in selenium. ">
       <div class="aspect-ratio--object">
           <div class="pa2 flex items-center justify-center h-100 w-100">
                <img alt="Random name cannot use this to link in selenium" class="db w-100 h-100 ipp object-cover" src="https://pic-c400-3.com/792647/00059768-ff6a-1304-0f8b-4060f001e784/c400.jpg?token=1578873600_78bae2898bc20e48508cdf6640fe7295ba0c429b85c57019936be6864df471e4">
           </div>
       </div>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Code I have tried, neither of which work:

```
photo = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="pa2 flex items-center justify-center h-100 w-100"]').click()
```

and:

```
photo = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="flex-none ph1 mt2 w-sixth-ns w-third"]').click()
```

Comment: That’s strange, do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to `click()` on the first image that appears on a page using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) client you to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='pictures']>div.aspect-ratio--object img.object-cover[src^='https://pic']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'pictures')]/div[@class='aspect-ratio--object']//img[contains(@class,'object-cover') and starts-with(@src, 'https://pic')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use the following xpath option.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class,'aspect-ratio') and contains(@href,'https://users')]//img[1]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```